# How to make Xcode "Run Script" to always run

Tags: xcode, build

I have a "run script" step that dynamically creates resources/files that I copy into the build dirs.  Every run of this script produces different content so I want it to run on every build.  The script gets run correctly on a clean build however once a build is made the step is not run again since no source has been modified.

I tried setting the input of the step to /dev/random but it does not seem to trigger a changed environment and does not re run the step.

Is there a way I can set this up so this step gets run ever time build is pressed, as opposed to only when the source is modified or clean?

Comment: I have a run script build phase in my project and it runs every time I press the Build button, whether files have been modified or not. I kno w this for sure for it copies the product to a specific location and the modified date stamp of the copy changes each time I press Build. Perhaps if you leave this input thing you mention?

Answer (score 5):

You should put the Run Script build phase in a separate Aggregate Target, and make your main target dependent on the Aggregate Target.  The Aggregate should be built every time.

Comment: Doesn't work well if you need environment variables like $DERIVED_FILES_DIR

Comment: Even when I put it in separate Aggregate Target, it is not running the script every time build happens.